# I'm trying to pass values from a php drop-down form (Index.php) to another php page (Display .php). But the post variable is empty

Tags: php

I am trying to pass the selected values ("users") from the drop down menu and send it to another php page (Display.php) but the values are not passed to Display.php. Below is the code for two pages: Index.php and Display.php.

Index.php

```
<?php
//Database connection
echo '<form action= "Display2.php" method= "post">';
    echo '<select name= "user" id="user">';
    echo '<option value="" selected="selected">All Users</option>';
        $result = $mysqli->query("Select * from users");
        while($object = $result->fetch_object()){
        echo "<option value= >".$object->Username."</option>";  
   }          
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="search" />';
    echo '</form>';
?>
```

Below  is the  Display.php page.

```
<?php
//Database connection
$_POST['user'];// This is where i am trying to get the values from Index.php but the post variable "$name" is empty.
$name = $_POST['user'];
echo $name ;
?>
```

Comment: share your complete code..

Comment: there is no `value= ` in `<option>` to pass

Comment: try like this `echo "<option value='".$object->Username."'>".$object->Username."</option>"; `

Comment: Thanks guys, it didn't work because there was no value ($object-Username) on the option. So added the value and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space between  method= "post" and that can make the post into GET parameter instead. Check it and try again.

Comment: Can you provide any reference to your ^^^ logic?

Comment: Can you provice examples and / or an explanation of the circumstances under which this behaviour occurs?